# Why does dconf-editor never appear in the dash?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

Whenever I launch an application through the Dash, that application gets brought to the start of the application list. However, this doesn't happen for dconf-editor -- it never appears in the Dash unless I search for it, even after launching it.

Why is dconf-editor special in this regard, and how can I make it behave like every other application?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think it is because there is no file `dconf-editor.desktop` in `/usr/share/applications`, while for most other apps there is a desktop file there.

Comment: @Jos: `/usr/share/applications/ca.desrt.dconf-editor.desktop` exists.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson ah, good catch. Sorry.